# Cannot get the LocalFeatureService to start when transporting code and data

Tags: arcgis-server, c#, geoprocessing-service

I have a C# project that uses a LocalFeatureService, a LocalGeoprocessingService and a LocalMapService. Everything runs fine when I run it at my own machine. However, when I transport the code and data (including packages) to another machine, and try to run the code, it is not able to start the Local Feature Service.

I'm not sure yet if the other services will start successfully, because it bombs at the Local Feature Service.
The error messages are:
      LocalServerException was unhandled. 
      Service Failed to initialize.   Error code 500
      Feature service creation failed

Everything is there, so what might I look for to understand why the service doesn't start?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by re-creating the map package and including the data rather than referencing the data.